# What's the difference between "every time" and "everytime"?

Tags: word-choice, differences, spacing

What's the difference between *everytime* and *every time*? I'm a little confused about them, they both seem to have same meaning. Excluding their spelling, are there any other differences between them?

Comment: ***Every time*** is always two separate words: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/every-time?q=everytime . Nonetheless people write it as a single word also : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=every+time%2C+everytime&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cevery%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ceverytime%3B%2Cc0, maybe it will be an accepted term before long,  (or is it already?). https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=everytime&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ceverytime%3B%2Cc0

Comment: *Everytime* is often used by native AmE speakers as a synonym for *whenever*. "*Everytime* I'm hungry, I eat some unbuttered popcorn." (https://books.google.com/books?id=KFFXBQAAQBAJ&pg=PT16&dq=%22everytime+i%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=31yFVf38FYW0yQToyoGoCg&ved=0CEwQ6AEwCg#v=onepage&q=%22everytime%20i%22&f=false)

Comment: *Every time* meaning "on every occasion" is different: "He gets me with that dribble glass every time." It is not usually part of a conditional clause.

Comment: If after some research (e.g. look up "every time" in a dictionary), you are still confused, please edit your answer and explain "why"? Your post is on hold, which gives you the time to improve/clarify/explain your question. I think this question, in view of the comments, has a *huge potential* for improvement, and be considered "useful" and "interesting" by the community.

Comment: Is **b/w** an abbreviation for "between". I thought "b/w" was short for "black and white", like w/o is for "without".

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The difference is that "everytime" is not a word, and "every time" means all occurrences:  "Every time I go to the beach, I get a sunburn."

You may be thinking of the difference between "everyday" and "every day."  The former is an adjective that can mean either daily or ordinary and common, and the latter is an adverb meaning each day:  "I don't have any fancy clothes.  I wear everyday clothes every day."

Comment: Are we going to say that  every time a word is spelled differently, it is no longer a word?  Some dictionaries list *everytime*:  https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/everytime, http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/everytime.

Comment: --- No, just me.

Comment: Then your answer is ambiguous, and you should clarify :)

Comment: @deadrat, I think "everytime" has become an acceptable alternate spelling for "every time".

Comment: "everytime" shows up in my spell check as a word. I did not add it to the spell check.

Comment: everyone comes here everyday from everywhere to read that "every time" is two words. makes sense. nope.